# Changing generic list indexes

Tags: arrays, generics

There is a class called Contact. 
I define the Contact in the list type and I assign random values ​​with foreach. `DataType == "address" 0.indis`, `DataType == "email" 1.indis`, `DataType == "telephonenumber" 2.indis` How can I print?

```
 public class Contact
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string DataVariable { get; set; }
            public string DataType { get; set; }
            public int PeopleId { get; set; }
        }


List<Contact> contacList = new List<Contact>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Console.writeline(contactlist) in the foreach body